# Edit a row in jQuery and dynamic id issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, edit

This table is in the loop. That is number of rows is dynamic.

```
<tr id="data">
    <td><input name="cb" type="checkbox" value="val"></td>
    <td>var 1</td>
    <td>var 2</td>
    <td>var 3</td>
</tr>
```

One edit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="edit" id="edit">
```

Each row has a checkbox. On click of the checkbox the entire row should be in the edit mode. I tried a lot of ways but still far away from the result. The second issue I faced is the id issue. Because the rows are dynamic so...

Comment: This question needs more information – how are you enabling edit mode? Is the operation an AJAX operation? What is the URL to which you post the modified data?

Answer (score 0):

You say

> This table is in the loop...

but you also have

```
<tr id="data">
```

`id` values [**must** be unique within the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#concept-id), so you'll have to modify that to not use `id`s.

But you don't need an `id` on each row. You can do this:

```
$('selector_for_the_table tr input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {

    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if (this.checked) {
        // make the row editable
    }
    else {
        // make the row uneditable
    }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/otisi3/2)

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are looking for is this, it uses a thing called "contentEditable" property, which enables editing HTML documents:

http://valums.com/edit-in-place/

More info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[name=checkbox_name").bind('onchange',function(){
$(this).parent('tr').html();//This line fetch current tr to edit 
});
```

Comment: The name of his checkbox is `cb`. Why change it? And he said he wanted to operate on the row, not the cell. And it's `change`, not `onchange`, with jQuery's `bind` (and anything else modern). AND this answer just duplicates the ground covered by answers already present.